# Create my own state monad transformer module hiding underlying state monad

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, state-monad

I'm learning about mtl and I wish learn the proper way to create new monads as modules (not as typical application usage).

As a simple example I have written a `ZipperT` monad ([complete code here](https://gist.github.com/josejuan/4211a9c9e3fc08e64e00)):

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, FunctionalDependencies, MultiParamTypeClasses, GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
module ZipperT (
  MonadZipper (..)
, ZipperT
, runZipperT
) where

import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.State

class Monad m => MonadZipper a m | m -> a where
    pushL :: a -> m ()
    pushR :: a -> m ()
    ...

data ZipperState s = ZipperState { left :: [s], right :: [s] }

newtype ZipperT s m a = ZipperT_ { runZipperT_ :: StateT (ZipperState s) m a }
                        deriving ( Functor, Applicative
                                 , Monad, MonadIO, MonadTrans
                                 , MonadState (ZipperState s))

instance (Monad m) => MonadZipper s (ZipperT s m) where
    pushL x = modify $ \(ZipperState left right) -> ZipperState (x:left) right
    pushR x = modify $ \(ZipperState left right) -> ZipperState left (x:right)
    ...

runZipperT :: (Monad m) => ZipperT s m a -> ([s], [s]) -> m (a, ([s], [s]))
runZipperT computation (left, right) = do
    (x, ZipperState left' right') <- runStateT (runZipperT_ computation) (ZipperState left right)
    return (x, (left', right'))
```

it's works and I can compose with other monads

```
import Control.Monad.Identity
import Control.Monad.State
import ZipperT

length' :: [a] -> Int
length' xs = runIdentity (execStateT (runZipperT contar ([], xs)) 0)
    where contar = headR >>= \x -> case x of
                     Nothing -> return ()
                     Just  _ -> do
                                    right2left
                                    (lift . modify) (+1)
                                 -- ^^^^^^^
                                    contar
```

But I wish to avoid the explicit `lift`.

- What is the correct way to create modules like this?
- Can I avoid the explicit `lift`? (I wish to hide the internal `StateT` structure of my `ZipperT`)

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that if you can write an instance of [`MonadState`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-State-Class.html#t:MonadState) for your transformer you can use `modify` without the `lift`:

```
instance Monad m => MonadState (ZipperT s m a) where
   ...
```

I must confess I am not sure about what part of the state `modify` should affect, though.

---

I've looked at the complete code. It seems that you already define

```
MonadState (ZipperState s) (ZipperT s m)
```

This already provides a `modify` which however modifies the wrong underlying state. What you actually wanted was to expose the state wrapped in `m`, provided that is a `MonadState` itself. This could theoretically be done with

```
instance MonadState s m => MonadState s (ZipperT s m) where
   ...
```

But now we have two `MonadState` instances for the same monad, causing a conflict.

---

I think I somehow solved this.

Here's what I did:

First, I removed the original `deriving MonadState` instance. I instead wrote

```
getZ :: Monad m => ZipperT s m (ZipperState s)
getZ = ZipperT_ get

putZ :: Monad m => ZipperState s -> ZipperT s m ()
putZ = ZipperT_ . put

modifyZ :: Monad m => (ZipperState s -> ZipperState s) -> ZipperT s m ()
modifyZ = ZipperT_ . modify
```

and replaced previous occurrences of `get,put,modify` in the `ZipperT` library with the above custom functions.

Then I added the new instance:

```
-- This requires UndecidableInstances
instance MonadState s m => MonadState s (ZipperT a m) where
   get = lift get
   put = lift . put
```

And now, the client code works without lifts:

```
length' :: [a] -> Int
length' xs = runIdentity (execStateT (runZipperT contar ([], xs)) 0)
    where contar :: ZipperT a (StateT Int Identity) ()
          contar = headR >>= \x -> case x of
                     Nothing -> return ()
                     Just  _ -> do
                                    right2left
                                    modify (+ (1::Int))
                                 -- ^^^^^^^
                                    contar
```

Comment: Yes, I can write `modify` but it affect to my underlying state not to my application state. Be able to write `modify` is not the matter, the matter is write the proper `modify` (and, in my example, if my application use one `StateT` must be able to use `modify` without `lift` to access to their `StateT`, he cannot, why? how?) :)

Comment: @josejuan I see. Check if the updated answer is what you wanted.

Comment: I tried to avoid the `MonadState` derivation but I thought that wrap all instances is not correct but, anyway, no too much instances would have to be. It might work! Thank you :)